# Group by and count unique values in several columns in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate, unique, distinct

I see a lot of examples of how to count values for one column. I can't find a solution for counting for several columns.

I have data like

```
city col1 col2 col3 col4
```

I want to group by city and count unique values in col1, col2, col3...

```
aggregate(. ~ city, hh2, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

I can count using aggregate, but it replaces city names with numbers and it's unclear how to revert it.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide better example data with some values for the variables.

Comment: Try changing the city column to character. `hh2$city <- as.character(hh2$city)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr::across`, which is a handy way to calculate across multiple columns:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  city = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3)),
  col1 = 1:6,
  col2 = 0,
  col3 = c(1:3, 4, 4, 4),
  col4 = 1:2
)

library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarize(across(col1:col4, n_distinct))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  city   col1  col2  col3  col4
* <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         3     1     3     2
2 B         3     1     1     2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm geting the same result as with aggregate though, numbered cities. It looks like it's because the format of the city column is <dbl+lbl>, the data itself comes from labeled .dta. So it's not really an aggregate or tidyverse issue. Do you know how can I separate them (numbers and labels)?

Comment: It's really difficult to help without a few rows of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like tidy data is what you're after. Here's an example with the tidyverse and subset of the mpg data set in ggplot2.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- mpg[c("model", 'cty', 'hwy')]

head(data) #to see the initial data layout.

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c('cty', 'hwy'), names_to = 'cat', values_to = 'values') %>%
  group_by(model, cat) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(values))
```